# nifi PublishKafka: Creating partitionID based on FlowFile attribute's value or Content (Json file's key) key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-producer-api

I would like to create one of attribute's values as partitionID for kafka topic. For example, my flow file attribute list has: `account_number` as one of the attribute. And `account_number can have different values eg, 111,222,121 etc`. Then `111, 222, 121 etc` will be PartitionID for my kafka topic, as I want to get messages ordered by timestamp.
I can't find any option for that in PublishKafka_0_10 processor in nifi.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PublishKafka processors currently do not let you directly control the partition id. The only way to control the it is by setting the "Paritioner Class" property to "DefaultPartitioner" and then specifying a message key. This would hash the message key to determine the partition.